# How to deploy static files to a separated machine

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'd like to do something like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'user@123.123.123.132:/home/static-files/'
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: yeah, i'd like to run manage.py collectstatic, ask me the root password, and copy them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org) to collect and deploy the static files to a remote server.

There's sample code in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/).

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib import project

env.roledefs['static'] = ['user@123.123.123.132',]    

# Where the static files get collected locally. Your STATIC_ROOT setting.
env.local_static_root = '/tmp/static'

# Where the static files should go remotely
env.remote_static_root = '/home/static-files'

@roles('static')
def deploy_static():
    local('./manage.py collectstatic')
    project.rsync_project(
        remote_dir = env.remote_static_root,
        local_dir = env.local_static_root,
        delete = True
    )
```

You would then deploy the static files by running:

```
fab deploy_static
```

Comment: where do I specify the remote host's ip?

Comment: You would provide it on the command line or add the IP to the `static` role. See http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/execution.html#defining-host-lists

Comment: I've updated the Django sample above with your host and path.

Comment: Thanks, it's working great. Now I have an extra question. What about media files? How can I put them in a separate server?

Comment: Do you mean the files under the MEDIA_ROOT setting? Those are user uploaded files and not typically deployed as part of your project. If you are allowing users to upload content then you'll need to design your application to use shared storage (NFS volume / S3 etc) or you'll need to develop your own process to replicate uploaded content to your servers.